# String was not recognised as a valid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, datetime, asp.net-ajax

in my asp.net c# application am using ajax calender extender for collecting datetime information.When i tried submit this page it shows that String was not recognised as a valid datetime.I tried different ways to convert,none works for me.

```
string date =Request.Form[ txtBookDate.UniqueID];

            DateTime yeer = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized
>   as a valid DateTime.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 78:             string date =Request.Form[ txtBookDate.UniqueID];
>   Line 79:  Line 80:             DateTime yeer =
>   Convert.ToDateTime(date); Line 81:             DateTime Bookdate =
>   Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToString()); Line 82:             int WedYear
>   = Bookdate.Year;
>
> Source File: D:\Sample
>   Project\AuditoriumNew\AuditoriumNew\Registration.aspx.cs    Line: 80
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
>   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
>   DateTimeStyles styles) +10404058    System.Convert.ToDateTime(String
>   value) +83    AuditoriumNew.Index.txtRent_TextChanged(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in D:\Sample
>   Project\AuditoriumNew\AuditoriumNew\Registration.aspx.cs:80
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) +116
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +50
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
>   +10    System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() +132    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1644
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

SOurce Code for ajax Extender

```
<asp:Label ID="bok" Text="Booking Date" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBookDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calender" runat="server" ImageUrl="img/cals/calender.png" />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="BookingDate" TargetControlID="txtBookDate" PopupButtonID="calender"
                        runat="server" PopupPosition="TopRight" DaysModeTitleFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" 
                        TodaysDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Actual Code

```
 protected void txtRent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float CentralAmnt;
            float renter;

            double rent = Convert.ToDouble(txtRent.Text);
            renter = float.Parse(rent.ToString());


            ///Calculate CTValue
            double CTValue = Convert.ToDouble(12.36 / 100);
            double CTax = CTValue;
            float CentralTax = float.Parse(CTax.ToString());

            CentralAmnt = renter * CentralTax;


            ///Calculate LT Value

            double LTax = 0.15;
            float LuxTax = float.Parse(LTax.ToString());
            float LuxAmnt = renter * LuxTax;
            string s = txtBookDate.Text;
            DateTime yeer;

             yeer = Convert.ToDateTime(s);

            //DateTime yeer = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
            DateTime Bookdate = Convert.ToDateTime(yeer.ToString());
            int WedYear = Bookdate.Year;
            if (WedYear < 2014)
            {
                float TotAmnt = renter + LuxAmnt;

                txtTotal.Text = TotAmnt.ToString();
                LuxuaryTaxAmnt = LuxAmnt;


            }
            else
            {
                float TotAmnt = renter + CentralAmnt + LuxAmnt;

                txtTotal.Text = TotAmnt.ToString();
                LuxuaryTaxAmnt = LuxAmnt;
                CentralTaxAmnt = CentralAmnt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Put a break point and see what value you get in `date` string.

Comment: No @Habib I think we should divine that value by ourselves :-)

Comment: Can you provide your ASPX page code?

Comment: Debug by 20 questions. Why make it hard for people to help you? Include ALL relevant information in your question. As it stands, your question isn't even a question. It's just a recounting of a sad story.

Comment: Make sure to 1:  provide complete sample that reproduces the problem (i.e. `DateTime.Parse("YerExactTextHere")` ), 2: read some of similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=String%20was%20not%20recognized%20as%20a%20valid%20DateTime before posting yours.

Comment: A.Jacky: I suggest that you ask a new question, omitting the full code and the full error message, and include only the contents of the string that you want to convert, and the function call (`Convert.ToDateTime(date)`) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If txtBookDate is empty and you decide to input a value in txtRent then you will continue to receive "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error because txtBookDate is EMPTY = NULL... OR if you did insert a Date, make sure it is in a reasonable format.**

So the question is: Do you enter a value into txtBookDate before you enter a value for txtRent?

Is there a reason why your code runs during txtRent_TextChanged? Is that the only way to do this?

Try the following, at least here I make sure that **yeer** has a "default" value so that you do not recieve "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." in this case:

```
DateTime yeer;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBookDate.Text))
    yeer = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBookDate.Text);
else
    yeer = new DateTime(9999, 12, 31);
```